# WebApi 2.1 Routing not behaving well when getting the "LINK"

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Here we go,

I have configured the following route:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "BatchLogs",
            routeTemplate: "api/Batches/{batchid}/Logs/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "BatchLogs", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

My method signature on the BatchLogsController looks like this:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(int batchId, int id)
```

I am getting the link like this (ex: BatchId = 7):

```
_urlHelper.Link("BatchLogs", new {batchId = batch.BatchId})
```

My expected result would be:

```
http://localhost:19828/api/Batches/7/Logs/
```

But I am getting:

```
http://localhost:19828/api/Batches/7/Logs/7
```

Why is this happening, and how should I go about fixing it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When generating links, Web API tries to combined the values provided by you explicitly + any values that are part of current request's route data.

So for example, in this case your Get action could have been selected with value of `batchId = 7` and `id = 7` and that is the reason you are seeing the following link:
`http://localhost:19828/api/Batches/7/Logs/7`

You might wonder why provide this kind of support, but its actually helpful in some situations. Exmaple: let's say your controller's Post action got selected and you just want to generate links to another action on the same controller(ex: Get(int id)), so in that case you can just say `_urlHelper.Link("DefaultApi", new {id = 10})`...so this way you need not specify the `controller` value again.

To force discarding the current request's route values, you need to explicitly nullify them.

Example:
`_urlHelper.Link("BatchLogs", new {batchId = batch.BatchId, id = ""})`

Comment: You are not allowed to assign null in anonymous type properties